# rudin's definition of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Here are some definitions given in my book:

> **Definition 2.31** By an open cover of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$ we mean a collection $\{G_\alpha \}$ of open subsets of $X$ such
>   that $E \subset \bigcup_\alpha G_\alpha$
>
> **Definition 2.32** A subset $K$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be compact if every open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover.
>
> ...
>   $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if the requirements of Definition 2.32 are
>   met.

I notice that the second definition says "open cover of $K$" instead of "open cover of $K$ in $X$". I'm a little confused because the very next theorem is about "relative compactness". I'm not sure where each $G_\alpha$ is located when we say "$K$ is compact relative to $Y$". If $X$ is a metric space, $E\subset Y\subset X$, $E$ is compact relative to $Y$, and $\{G_\alpha \}$ is an "open cover of $E$", are each $G_\alpha$ elements of $Y$ or $X$?

Comment: If it's compact "relative to $Y$", then the $G_\alpha$ are open **in $Y$**.  He doesn't clarify that in the first definition because there is no ambiguity; there is no alternative meaning of an "open set" in this context.

Comment: $K$ is assumed to be a subset of $X$, so Rudin means a cover of $K$ by opens in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Each $G_{\alpha}$ is contained in both $X$ and $Y$, but they're necessarily open in $Y$.